# Список стандартных библиотек Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

Пожалуйста дайте список стандартных библиотек(Library Path) с вашей делфы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Зачем это нужно: ставил сторонние компоненты и нечаянно стёр пути к стандартным, не знаю, как их восстановить в исходном виде.*

Comment: Заминусили даже не объяснив почему, но все же я надеюсь что хоть у кого то стоит делфи и там есть эти данные)

Comment: ну если тебя на русском и английском stackoverflow минусуют, то это должно, я думаю, о чём-то говорить

Comment: данные есть. Но совершенно непонятно - какой профит вы хотите получить из этой информации, зачем она вам. И какую пользу эти сведения могут принести тем, кто потом наткнется на этот вопрос. Детализируйте вопрос, покажите что его решение может пригодиться и минусы прекратятся.

Comment: @progtask.ru ну так стань пожалуйста тем человеком который разъяснит за что минусуют

Comment: @kami? да пожалуйста, если никто не может понять, с удовольствием объясню. Ставил вот вдруг сторонние компоненты и нечаянно стер пути к стандартным, как их восстановить - не знаю, поиск по гуглу ничего не дал, вопрос цитировать?

Comment: пожалуйста. Все же, не думаю, что такой вопрос соответствует формату СО, посему - ответ вам в комментарии и скорее всего, вопрос потрут: `$(BDS)\lib;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;$(BDS)\RaveReports\Lib`

Comment: @kami оформите пожалуйста как ответ, я отмечу как верный!

Comment: А мне казалось, что на делфи поддерживаются старые программы и на нем уже не пишут

Comment: @gil9red вам действительно казалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартные пути для Delphi 2010:
`$(BDS)\lib;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\‌​Dcp;$(BDS)\include;$‌​(BDS)\RaveReports\Li‌​b`.

Обратите внимание, что различные наборы компонентов (DevExpress, JEDI,...) и дополнения (например, MadExcept) могут добавлять в эти пути необходимые им для работы данные.

Помимо этого, даже стандартные пути отличаются в разных версиях. Особенно это проявилось с появлением возможности сборки для разных платформ, когда было внедрено понятие `$(Platform)`